# Looping through associative array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I'm using curl to return some JSON from an API and I'm using `json_decode($result,true);`

I have managed to access the `title` but I need to loop through the whole array and output the `title`, `url`, `location` and `picture`.

I'm doing a `foreach` to print all the content:

```
<?php
    foreach ($json as $value) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($json);

        echo $json['data'][2]['title'];
    }
?>
```

What blocks me its how do I access every element.

```
Array
(
    [paging] => Array
        (
            [total_items] => 33
            [current_page] => 1
            [total_pages] => 3
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 776583
                    [title] => NAME
                    [url] =>URL
                    [status] => open
                    [current_status] => open
                    [location] => a, a
                    [programmes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [short_name] => SHORT NAME
                        )

                    [applications_count] => 5
                    [is_favourited] => 
                    [branch] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 319532
                            [name] => International SOS - 1
                            [organisation_id] => 318911
                            [profile_photo_url] => URL
                            [url] => URL
                        )

                    [views] => 248
                    [duration_min] => 22
                    [duration_max] => 24
                    [applications_close_date] => 2016-09-06T00:00:00.000Z
                    [earliest_start_date] => 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z
                    [latest_end_date] => 2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z
                    [profile_photo_urls] => Array
                        (
                            [original] => PIC URL
                            [medium] => PIC URL
                            [thumb] => PIC URL
                        )

                    [cover_photo_urls] => PNG IMG
                    [created_at] => 2016-08-30T03:24:41Z
                    [updated_at] => 2016-08-30T15:36:02Z
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 774984
                    [title] => NAME
                    [url] => URL
                    [status] => open
                    [current_status] => open
                    [location] => Bonn, Germany
                    [programmes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [short_name] => NAME
                        )

                    [applications_count] => 128
                    [is_favourited] => 
                    [branch] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 287321
                            [name] => Deutsche Post DHL Group
                            [organisation_id] => 286836
                            [profile_photo_url] => PHOTO
                            [url] => URL
                        )

                    [views] => 1331
                    [duration_min] => 48
                    [duration_max] => 48
                    [applications_close_date] => 2016-09-04T00:00:00.000Z
                    [earliest_start_date] => 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z
                    [latest_end_date] => 2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z
                    [profile_photo_urls] => Array
                        (
                            [original] => PIC
                            [medium] => PIC
                            [thumb] => PIC
                        )

                    [cover_photo_urls] => PIC
                    [created_at] => 2016-08-23T19:47:04Z
                    [updated_at] => 2016-08-24T06:35:58Z
                )
```

Comment: `foreach ($json['data'] as $item) echo $item['title'], $item['url'];`

Comment: So you want to loop through your subArray `data`, then in the foreach loop you just access each key you want.

Comment: @deceze In your example I can`t access a subarray in order to get the image

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    foreach ($json as $value) {    

       foreach($value['data'] as $inner){   //looping json['data']
             echo $inner['id'];
             echo $inner['title'];

             foreach($inner['programmes'] as $in_inner){  //looping json['data']['element_number']['programmers']
                 echo $in_inner['id'].':'.$in_inner['short_name'];
              }

       }

    }

?>
```

In this way you can iterate through inner arrays.

Comment: It dose' work for me. Instead this is working foreach ($json['data'] as $item) echo $item['title'], $item['url'];